# dragging an UIImageView on an UIView always stacks the image under the UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am rather new to iOS and swift 3 programming. At the moment I am working on a little learning project. I have the following problem. 
On my screen I have 4 UIViews and 4 UIImageViews. The app allows to “drag and drop” an image onto one of the UIViews. This works pretty well so far. I use Pan Gesture Recognisers for the dragging of UIImages. But for some reason one of the UIViews seems to be in front of the image, meaning that I can drop the image to this area, but I cannot see it - it is layered under the UIView. The other three behave properly, the UIImageView is layered on top of the UIView. In the viewDidLoad() function of the view controller I set the background color of the UIViews to grey. If I don’t do that, the image will be displayed even on the fourth UIView.

I have checked for differences between the four UIView objects but cannot find any. I also tried to recreate the UIView by copying it from one of the the other three. 
So my question is: Is there any property which defines that the UIView is layered on top or can be sent to back so that other objects are layered on top of it? Or is there anything else I am missing? Any hints would be very appreciated.

I was not quite sure which parts of the code are relevant, so I posted some of it (but still guess that this is rather a property of the UIView…)

This is where I set the background of the UIViews

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    lbViewTitle.text = "\(viewTitle) \(level) - \(levelPage)"

    if (level==0) {
        print("invalid level => EXIT")
    } else {
        loadData(level: level)

        originalPositionLetter1 = letter1.center
        originalPositionLetter2 = letter2.center
        originalPositionLetter3 = letter3.center
        originalPositionLetter4 = letter4.center

        dropArea1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        dropArea2.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        dropArea3.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        dropArea4.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }
}
```

This is the code that moves the image:

```
@IBAction func hadlePan1(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    moveLetter(sender: sender, dropArea: dropArea4, movedImage: letter1, originalPosition: originalPositionLetter1)
}

func moveLetter(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer, dropArea : UIView, movedImage : UIImageView, originalPosition : CGPoint) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)

            if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
                let here = sender.location(in: self.view)
                if (dropArea.frame.contains(here)) {
                    movedImage.center = dropArea.center
                } else {
                    movedImage.center = originalPosition
                }

            }


        }
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that may be useful to you: `UIView.sendSubview(toBack:)` and `UIView.bringSubview(toFront:)`.

What I think you should do is to call `bringSubview(toFront:)` when you start dragging the image:

```
func moveLetter(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer, dropArea : UIView, movedImage : UIImageView, originalPosition : CGPoint) {
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: movedImage) // <--- add this line!
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = sender.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
            let here = sender.location(in: self.view)
            if (dropArea.frame.contains(here)) {
                movedImage.center = dropArea.center
            } else {
                movedImage.center = originalPosition
            }

        }


    }
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for mentioning the above mentioned functions. Unfortunately they don't seem to solve my issue though. I am still playing with it a bit and try to provide more detail.